# How to move a single page of content to a new domain

Tags: seo, google, domains, blog

I am trying to figure out best-practise for moving a single page of content from one domain to another in a way that will preserve search engine ranking. I have found plenty of instructions for wholesale domain moves, but this situation is slightly different.

I have a blog, one page of which gets a lot of search traffic for a specific term. I would like to take that one page of content and move it to an entirely new domain, which I will then use to start adding new content to.

My plan so far:

- register the new domain
- remove the single page of content from the old domain
- put up the single page of content on the new domain
- set up a 301 redirect for the URL of the page on the old domain, pointing to the new domain

Is this the right way to do it? Is there anything else I need to do in order to keep Google happy?

Comment: You weren't be obliged to ask the question, your plan is the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a good start. To add to your steps:

- Check to make sure that you don't have any internal links to the old page in your content or sitemap, and if so change them to the new URL.
- Check for external links in Google Webmaster Tools, and if possible, try to contact the webmaster of the referring site to change them to the new URL.
- To avoid any potential for duplicate content issues, in case it appears elsewhere, you might add a [Canonical](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) link to the page.
- Submit your updated sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools, and other search engines.
- Use the "Fetch As Google" function in Google Webmaster Tools so that Google will re-crawl and index your site. See this for more information on that:
  [Ask Google to crawl a page or site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1352276)

Comment: Great answer, thanks - I completely forgot about the checking for internal links.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a good question, and will likely help others too.

Comment: I added info about using a canonical link, as a precaution (it can't hurt).