# Will moving some ecommerce products from one domain to another with redirects cause SEO penalties?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, 404

I'm the developer for a small online webstore. We've just moved a subsection of products (the bodyboarding products), off surfhq.co.uk on to bodyboardhq.co.uk to sell them there instead.

We didn't want to sell on both stores as search engines don't like duplicate pages - and domain2.co.uk has much better seo for bodyboarding - the site has been run as an active blog for sometime - we've only just added the cart.

My question is, should I be using a 301 redirect on the old product pages (sending users to the new pages on domain2.co.uk), or should I just serve up a 404 not found? Google search currently lists a lot of broken links (I've gone down the 404 route for fear that permanent redirects will result in one of our sites being penalised).

EDIT

My question is not answered [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5392/ecommerce-item-deleted-by-user-301-rediret-to-home-page-or-404-not-found) where the 301 is to the home page and the products have been deleted. My products have been moved to another domain (the 301 would be to the product on the new domain). Also I'm concerned with the SEO effect on both domains.

Comment: I actually think this is a much simpler issue than the question it's been marked a duplicate of. You're permanently moving some pages to a different domain, so clearly a 301 for each is the correct approach.

Comment: @TimFountain that sounds correct to me - my fear was that one or other domain might be penalised if it became clear they were effectively the same store.

Comment: searching for the more general situation of moving a page to a new domain (with no mention of concern for the seo on both domains) - I found this useful question - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49794/how-to-move-a-single-page-of-content-to-a-new-domain