# Moving a secondary site form a www.example.com/subdirectory to another www domain

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have added all my websites on Webmaster Tools (Google Search Console), but I have a question about moving a different site from a subdirectory to another `www` domain. I added on Webmaster Tools and verified `www.example.com`, and I also have `www.example.com/example2/` verified and indexed. I bought a separate domain and I want to move `www.example.com/example2` to `www.example2.com`.
In this moment `www.example.com/example2/` have already 301 redirect to `www.example2.com`

The question is, If I request a change of a address in Google Search Console from `www.example.com/example2` to move to new domain, will it not affect `www.example.com` from its ranking? Will it not redirect all root domain to new site i am pointing?

Comment: I renamed `www.site.com` to `www.example.com`, `www.site.com/othersite/` to `www.example.com/example2/` and `www.othersite.com` to `www.example2.com` which will be more generic than `site.com` or `othersite.com`

Comment: Here's similar thing for you: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89978/moving-folders-content-to-a-new-domain-what-seo-steps-to-take

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this will not work. I believe when attempting a change of address you will get a message like "Restricted to root level domains and subdomains only"

If you have 301 redirects in place, they will do the work anyway.